# C++ while statement for failed functions?

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

As an amater programmer, this confuses me. I'm probably just missing something. In C++ code that I've seen things like this:

```
while (cin.get(c)) {...}
```

almost as though it was a try statement. If the statement succeeds, it's like the function returned true, if not, it's like it returned false. I've seen things like this a lot, sometimes in other languages. How does it work? I'm I just missing something (like the function returning false if it doesn't work.)? If not, does this work in all languages?

Comment: I think what you are looking for, is something along the lines of "truthy" and "falsey" values. What these are varies by language .. for instance, 0 is a "falsey" value (in C/C++/JavaScript/etc), while every other integer is a "truthy" value.

Comment: `cin.get()` reads a single character including a white space and stores it in the variable, in your case c. It can also be called `c=cin.get()`. You can also use `cin.get()` to pause the screen for until the user presses ENTER. Knowing that, and having not seen that example, seems like an infinite loop.

Comment: @RobertoWilko that seems to me like something that loops until EOF (ctrl + D) is reached.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII-Good point, I went off assuming things, they can break out of it with (ctrl + C)(?) as well. I would probably use a more specific way of handling that like a yesno `char` where the user gets an acknowledged chance to quit, but that's MO.

Comment: This isn't a general thing.  Some functions return things that can be used to determine success or failure, others don't.  You just have to look at the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/get/
The version that you are using is the second (`istream& get ( char& c );`). In C++, as pst said, any value different of 0 or NULL will be true, otherwise it will be false. In your case, every call of cin.get will return *this, wich will be true, so, you will get an infinite loop until some "problem" occurs like reading an EOF "char" (^C => Ctrl+C) in Windows).

Comment: What does it return if it encounters a problem exactly? Does it just raise an error?

Comment: @Mike: When a problem occurs, the stream sets flag(s) on itself (depending on the type of error) and still returns itself.  The stream has an operator to convert itself to a `bool` or `void*` (i forget), and that operator returns a falsy value (`false` or null, respectively) if any of those flags are set.

Answer (score 3):

A C++ reference would note that the return value of the `get(char_type &)` method is `*this` with the type `basic_istream &` ([1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)). The `basic_istream` inherits from `basic_ios` which has a conversion operator that essentially returns false if there is an I/O failure, and true otherwise ([2](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)).

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement evaluates an expression for truth... a true expression could evaluate directly to a boolean with the value `true`, or to some value that can be implicitly converted to `true` (for example, a numeric/pointer value is true if non-0).

Functions can return `true` or `false`, or return some object that has a conversion operator to a boolean or numeric type.

In this case, `cin.get(c)` returns a reference to the `cin` object, which can be implicitly converted to a boolean (from `void*` - see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/) to check for success or failure of input operations.

This does not work for all functions, or all languages - it only works for those functions that happen to return a boolean or numeric value that makes sense to test in this way.  For example:

```
if (std::cin >> a >> b)    // true if both inputted successfully...

if (my_vector.capacity())   // useless? - capacity may be >0 "true" irrespective of size()

if (my_vector.empty())      // makes sense - returns a boolean

if (my_vector.size())       // makes sense - returns a number, non-0 is "true"
                            // dubious style as a change from vector to list would require
                            // a change to !empty() to maintain O(1) performance in C++03
```

Answer (score 0):

The IOStreams library is deliberately designed this way. Those operations return a reference to the stream you're operating on, and the stream is convertible to `bool` with a value depending on its state.

I can see why it may be an unexpected idiom, but it does make for some expressive code.